# How do I convert a tab separated file into comma separated file in Mac OSX using sed?

Tags: macos, sed

I am doing a MySQL query from the terminal and trying to convert the output from a tab-separated file to a comma-separated file. I've tried the following with no luck:

```
... mysql query | sed 's/\t/,/g'
... mysql query | sed 's/\\t/","/g'
... mysql query | sed 's/\\t/\\",\\"/g'
```

and various combinations of these with no luck.

Comment: don't. just run your query as `select ... into outfile 'foo.csv' fields terminated by ','`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the solution here. **You have to insert the tab by doing "ctrl+v" then hit the "tab" button to manually insert the tab.** For some reason, sed in the Mac OSX terminal doesn't like the \t regex.

```
... mysql query | sed 's/   /,/g'
```

Comment: Alternative you can use C strings: `sed 's/'$'\t''/,/g'`

Comment: Or, as long as the sed command is this simple,  `sed $'s/\t/,/g'`. Note that `$'...'` requires bash.

Comment: Actually, I don't see how the terminal enters into this equation. If `sed 's/\t/,/g'` does not work, doesn't `sed` fail to interpret `\t` correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Another, IMHO simpler, option is to use `tr` to transliterate tabs into commas, like this:

```
mysql query | tr '\t' ','
```